# Error while updating laravel from 6.03 to 6.18

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have this error when trying to upgrade my Laravel from 6.03 to 6.18
Could not delete D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor/laravel/framework\src\Illuminate:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed

```
PS D:\xampp\htdocs\XXXXX> composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 35 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating laravel/framework (v6.0.3 => v6.18.35):     Update failed (Could not delete D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor/laravel/framework\src\Illuminate:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]?
  - Removing laravel/framework (v6.0.3)


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor/laravel/framework\src\Illuminate:
  This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

PS D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm>
```

Comment: originaly ver 6.03 was working fine and I installed vue.js then when trying to update this error happened

Comment: and now when I try to open my webapplication from brower I get this error :Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor\composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try removing D:\xampp\htdocs\BaladyFreshFarm\vendor/laravel/framework\src\Illuminate
manually. If this not work, try restart and turn off antivirus, then try again.

Answer (score 3):

Same happened with me and after several hours of debugging i found out:

- Make sure your vscode or powershell or cmd has "Administrative" rights.
- Make sure your web server is working fine.

**What not to do:** 
In my situation nothing was wrong with Proxy and all it was just permission and working web
server. But i have to reinstall xampp to properly resolve this issue because i had tampered some files while debugging

Answer (score 1):

Run your IDE or terminal like administrator, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today. Delete the vendor folder then do a `composer install`. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved mine:

1. Open your CMD as administrator
2. cd into your project name
3. Go to your Anti-virus software and click on settings, select exceptions
4. Then add this path C:\xampp\htdocs and click on ok
5. Go back to your CMD and type composer require laravel/ui.......this worked for me